# How to make Bootstrap's datapicker input with only day without time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datapicker

This is my code, I need delete time and put day before date when select date

```
<div class="input-group input-group-icon date" id="datetimepicker1">
   <input type="text" class="form-control dat" placeholder="25.8.2015">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
    </span>
</div>

$(function () {
 $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  locale: 'hr'
 });
});
```

Comment: nice pc skills a picture of a picture :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small 'd' equal writing out the text while big 'D' equal numbers.

Here is a [DEMO - JS-FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/g03ut55c/)

```
      $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({

        format: 'ddd D.MM.YYYY'

      });
```

Comment: Ismet you need to change Salmin's #mydate to your own #datetimepicker1

Comment: i change that, and i use datetimepicke

Comment: I updated the code and the Demo. Now it should work (Now I'm using bootstrap dateTimePicker)

Comment: Thanks bro, it work, how first letter to be upercase

Comment: ned. 3.1.2016, I need Ned 3.1.2015, usput odakle si Salmine.

Comment: In my demo it shows Ned. Do you have different locales?
Iz crne gore sam ali zivim u svedsku :)

Comment: I use locale hr, i have #datetimepicker1 and #datetimepicker2, šta radis, koji program koristis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95555/discussion-between-salmin-skenderovic-and-ismet).